# Can I stop predictive typing from suggesting emojis?

Tags: emoji, auto-complete

I hardly ever use emojis in my messages. Recently, I used one in a text and now predictive typing always recommends emojis for my words.

Is there any way that I can keep predictive typing on, but not have it suggest emojis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround in this [apple discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7680299?start=0&tstart=0) from 2016:

go to:

Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards > Edit > Delete Emoji.

this will remove emojis from your keyboard, and as somebody commented, will also change the predictions.

and a quote from another person, more recent comment from feb '17:

> I have discovered a solution however, install GBoard - Googles
>   keyboard. You can turn of emoji suggestions in settings and it's
>   significantly quicker. Also the glide function works well.